# AWS Glue ETL Job Error: Illegal escaper \\

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I'm getting this error on my AWS Glue ETL Job. Got no idea what it could possibly be. Reading the logs honestly does my head in... (also makes it 10x frustrating when you have to wait 10mins before it shits itself).

For context: I'm trying to read from an Athena table which is pointing to an S3 bucket then use this job to output into consolidated csv's (split by partition_0,partition_1) into a seperate S3 bucket.

If someone could help, I will be greatly indebted.

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

## @params: [JOB_NAME]
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)
## @type: DataSource
## @args: [database = "twitterappdatalake", table_name = "twitterdatalake", transformation_ctx = "datasource0"]
## @return: datasource0
## @inputs: []
pushDownPredicate = "(partition_0=='Politics' and partition_1=='HongKong')"
datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "twitterappdatalake", table_name = "twitterdatalake", transformation_ctx = "datasource0",push_down_predicate=pushDownPredicate)
## @type: ApplyMapping
## @args: [mapping = [("created_at", "string", "created_at", "string"), ("file_name", "string", "file_name", "string"), ("followers", "long", "followers", "long"), ("friends", "long", "friends", "long"), ("group_name", "string", "group_name", "string"), ("location", "string", "location", "string"), ("retweet_count", "long", "retweet_count", "long"), ("screenname", "string", "screenname", "string"), ("search_query", "string", "search_query", "string"), ("text", "string", "text", "string"), ("twitter_id", "long", "twitter_id", "long"), ("username", "string", "username", "string"), ("polarity", "double", "polarity", "double"), ("partition_0", "string", "partition_0", "string"), ("partition_1", "string", "partition_1", "string")], transformation_ctx = "applymapping1"]
## @return: applymapping1
## @inputs: [frame = datasource0]
applymapping1 = ApplyMapping.apply(frame = datasource0, mappings = [("created_at", "string", "created_at", "string"), ("file_name", "string", "file_name", "string"), ("followers", "long", "followers", "long"), ("friends", "long", "friends", "long"), ("group_name", "string", "group_name", "string"), ("location", "string", "location", "string"), ("retweet_count", "long", "retweet_count", "long"), ("screenname", "string", "screenname", "string"), ("search_query", "string", "search_query", "string"), ("text", "string", "text", "string"), ("twitter_id", "long", "twitter_id", "long"), ("username", "string", "username", "string"), ("polarity", "double", "polarity", "double"), ("partition_0", "string", "partition_0", "string"), ("partition_1", "string", "partition_1", "string")], transformation_ctx = "applymapping1")


## @type: DataSink
## @args: [connection_type = "", connection_options = {"path": "s3://outputbuckettwitter/outputcsv"}, format = "csv", transformation_ctx = "datasink2"]
## @return: datasink2
## @inputs: [frame = applymapping1]

format_options_json={"escaper":'\\', "seperator":",", "quoteChar": '"', "withHeader":True}
datasink2 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = applymapping1, connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path": "s3://outputbuckettwitter"}, format = "csv", transformation_ctx = "datasink2",format_options=format_options_json)
job.commit()
```

[MyError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PZIz.png)

Comment: The docs suggest that `escaper` must be a single character, except in a small group of specified cases (`\n`, `\r`, `\t`, and `\0`) - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-format.html#aws-glue-programming-etl-format-csv

Comment: Can you try "escaper" : "\"" ? This should escape \

Comment: Thanks heaps peeps! I retried with escaper as "\" and it works now! 

Will close this one